# Trace(AB) = Trace(BA) for rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, random-matrices

Given A is $m\times n$ and B is a $n \times m$ matrix, can we say trace(AB) = trace(BA)? It worked for a few examples with $m = 2$ and $n = 3$.

Comment: It's generally true. Just write out the definition of the matrix product and the trace. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252272/trace-is-invariant-under-cyclic-permutation-even-with-rectangular-matrices-invol?rq=1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, It is true. Trace(AB) = Trace(BA) for rectangular matrices. 
You can rewrite the expression used for calculating trace to prove this.

tr(AB) = $\sum_{i=1}^{m}(AB)_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}B_{ji} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m}B_{ji}A_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}(BA)_{jj} $= tr(BA)

For more references, you can see the answers in this link : [Read more here..](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314142/trace-of-ab-trace-of-ba)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/765233)

Comment: Thanks.I'll make sure of this in my future answers.. :)

Comment: you are welcome. You will do well.