# How to show that the multivariate normal depends on the data only through $\Sigma x_n$ and $\Sigma x_n x^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I've shown something similar for the 1-dimensional case. That $\Sigma x_n$ is the sufficient statistic of the gaussian mean and $\Sigma x_n$,$\Sigma x_n^2$ are the sufficient statistics of the gaussian variance.

However, im stuck on the multivariate example.
How did we show that the log likelihood depends on the data only through $\Sigma x_n$ and $\Sigma x_n^Tx_n$?

[image: The perceptron criterion is stated to be:]

I suppose we only look at the exponent terms and i made the exponent into:

[image]

How to move the $x_n^T$ and $x_n$ together when the inverse variance is in between them?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231714/sufficient-statistic-for-bivariate-or-multivariate-normal,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you look at the exponent.

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N(X_n^T\Sigma^{-1}X_n-2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}X_n+\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu)=N\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu-2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^NX_n+\sum_{n=1}^NX_n^T\Sigma^{-1}X_n.$$

You need to deal with the quantity $X_n^T\Sigma^{-1}X_n,$ which is a scalar. We can write $X_n^T\Sigma^{-1}X_n=\text{Trace}(X_n^T\Sigma^{-1}X_n)=\text{Trace}(\Sigma^{-1}X_nX_n^T),$
where we use the fact that [Trace of AB = Trace of BA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314142/trace-of-ab-trace-of-ba/1314150])

Moreover, trace is linear, $\text{Trace}(A+B)=\text{Trace}(A)+\text{Trace}(B).$ [Properties of trace](https://planetmath.org/proofofpropertiesoftraceofamatrix)

Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^NX_n^T\Sigma^{-1}X_n=\sum_{n=1}^N\text{Trace}(\Sigma^{-1}X_nX_n^T)=\text{Trace}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\Sigma^{-1}X_nX_n^T\right)=\text{Trace}\left(\Sigma^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^NX_nX_n^T\right),$
which only depends on $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^NX_nX_n^T.$